# add drag and drop to vuetify's select

Tags: vue.js, drag-and-drop, vuetify.js

I've found an example of two for drag and drop with Vuetify's data table, but I can't get it to work with a select component.  Here's what I'm trying:

```
      <template>
            <v-select
                v-model="displayingRows"
                :items="rowItems"
                :menu-props="{ maxHeight: '400' }"
                label="Select"
                multiple
            >
                <Draggable v-model="displayingRows">
                <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
                    <!-- HTML that describe how select should render selected items -->
                    {{ data.item.text }} - {{ data.item.value }}
                </template>
                <template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
                    <!-- HTML that describe how select should render items when the select is open -->
                    {{ data.item.text }} 
                </template>
                </Draggable>
            </v-select>
      </template>
```

and the js

```
<script> 
    import Draggable from 'vuedraggable'
    export default {
        components: {
              Draggable
        },
        data(){
             return {
                   displayingRows: [],
                   rowItems: [{text: 'orange', value: 1}, {text: 'banana', value: 2}, {text: 'peach', value: 3}]
             }
        }
    } 
</script>
```

The drag and drop doesn't work at all.  Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Try to use:

```
options="{group:'draggableGroup'}"
```

on each draggable item like this:

```
Draggable v-model="displayingRows" :options="{group:'draggableGroup'}"
```

Answer (score 2):

I made draggable v-autocomplete code as jsfiddle.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hakgeumkim/1d4ohjxg/54/)

- `v-select` series has #selection, It provide template as like a v-for.
- Each selection is one list with one element.
- So, set all lists with id = index
- When event `:move` in `<draggable>`, Set current dragged element's properties.
- When dragged(`changed`), insert current element to array `items` at exact index.
- And remove old one.

The key is... draggable list `id` is `items`'s `index`.

Code below...

html template

```html
<div data-app id="app">
    <v-autocomplete
        v-model="selectedSync"
        :items="itemsSync"
        chips
        multiple
    >
        <template #selection="data">
            <draggable
                :id="data.index"
                :list="selectedSync"
                v-bind="dragOptionsChips"
                :move="move"
                @change="change"
            >
                <v-chip
                    draggable
                    v-model="selectedSync[data.index]"
                    :key="data.item"
                    @mousedown.stop
                    @click.stop
                >
                  {{data.item}}
                </v-chip>
            </draggable>
        </template>
    </v-autocomplete>
</div>
```

js script

```js
new Vue({
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    dragged: {
      from: -1,
      to: -1,
      newIndex: -1
    },
    selectedSync: ['a'],
    itemsSync: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
  },
  methods: {
    move: function(value) {
      this.dragged = {
        from: parseInt(value.from.id),
        to: parseInt(value.to.id),
        newIndex: value.draggedContext.futureIndex,
      }
    },
    change: function(value) {
      if (value.removed) {
        // insert
        this.selectedSync.splice(this.dragged.to+this.dragged.newIndex,0, this.selectedSync[this.dragged.from])
        // delete
        if (this.dragged.from < this.dragged.to) // LTR
          this.selectedSync.splice(this.dragged.from, 1)
        else // RTL
          this.selectedSync.splice(this.dragged.from + 1, 1)
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    dragOptionsChips() {
      return {
        animation: 200,
        group: "group",
        disabled: false,
        ghostClass: "ghost",
        sort: true,
      };
    }
  },
})
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.